# Reddit mirror encryption challenge

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, unit-testing, caesar-cipher

While reviewing [Encryption using a mirror field](/q/131660/9357), I decided to write my own solution from scratch.  The [challenge, from Reddit's /r/dailyprogrammer](https://redd.it/4m3ddb), is to implement a monoalphabetic substitution cipher whose key is derived from a pictorial 13×13 grid.  Here's a simplified 5×5 example:

> ```
>  abcde
> A \   f
> B     g
> C   \ h
> D     i
> E   / j
>  FGHIJ
> ```
>
> The 5×5 grid above defines 20 mappings, some of which are:
>
> - `A` maps to `G`, because a laser beam heading right from the `A` would hit the `\` mirror and be deflected down to `G`.
> - Conversely, `G` maps to `A` through the reverse path.
> - `B` maps to `g`, and vice versa, as the horizontal beam is uninterrupted.
> - `C` maps to `E`, and vice versa, as the beam is reflected twice.
> - `I` maps to `j`, and vice versa.

The actual input is provided as a 13×13 grid of `/`, `\`, and space characters, without the row and column labels.  I've implemented the option to accept the key as a filename if one is provided on the command line, else it will be read from the first 13 lines of standard input.  Thereafter, the program acts as a filter for text on standard input.

I've also implemented a [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), which you can run using `python -v -m doctest programname`.  The presence of backslashes has forced me to write it in an ugly way; any suggestion for a better way to write it would be appreciated.

```
"""
Perform the mirror encryption challenge in https://redd.it/4m3ddb
"""

from fileinput import input as fileinput
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
from sys import argv, stdin

def grid_to_translation(grid):
    """
    Given a mirror field, construct a translation table suitable for use with
    str.maketrans().  The grid may be any iterable; only the first 13 lines
    will be taken from it.

    >>> # Using a string replacement as literal backslashes are hard to write.
    >>> input = (line.replace('x', chr(92)) for line in [
    ...     '   xx  /x    ',
    ...     '            x',
    ...     '   /         ',
    ...     '      x     x',
    ...     '    x        ',
    ...     '  /      /   ',
    ...     'x  /      x  ',
    ...     '     x       ',
    ...     'x/           ',
    ...     '/            ',
    ...     '          x  ',
    ...     '    x/       ',
    ...     '   /       / ',
    ... ])
    >>> translation = grid_to_translation(input)
    >>> 'TpnQSjdmZdpoohd'.translate(translation)
    'DailyProgrammer'
    >>> 'Code Review'.translate(translation)
    'Amrh LhOnhN'
    >>> 'Amrh LhOnhN'.translate(translation)
    'Code Review'
    """
    RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, UP = (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)

    LAUNCH = dict(      # Top, right, left, and bottom edges
        [(c, ((-1, col), DOWN))  for col, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[:13])]
      + [(c, ((row, 13), LEFT))  for row, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[13:])]
      + [(c, ((row, -1), RIGHT)) for row, c in enumerate(ascii_uppercase[:13])]
      + [(c, ((13, col), UP))    for col, c in enumerate(ascii_uppercase[13:])]
    )

    EDGES = {pos: c for c, (pos, _) in LAUNCH.items()}

    # REFLECT[barrier][incoming_direction] gives the outgoing direction
    REFLECT = {
        '/': {
                    DOWN: LEFT,
            RIGHT: UP,      LEFT: DOWN,
                    UP: RIGHT,
        },
        '\\': {
                    DOWN: RIGHT,
            RIGHT: DOWN,    LEFT: UP,
                    UP: LEFT,
        },
        ' ': {
                    DOWN: DOWN,
            RIGHT: RIGHT,   LEFT: LEFT,
                    UP: UP,
        },
    }

    def trace(pos, aim):
        pos = (pos[0] + aim[0], pos[1] + aim[1])
        while not pos in EDGES:
            aim = REFLECT[grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]][aim]
            pos = (pos[0] + aim[0], pos[1] + aim[1])
        return EDGES[pos]

    grid = iter(grid)
    grid = [next(grid) for _ in range(13)]
    mapping = {ord(c): trace(pos, aim) for c, (pos, aim) in LAUNCH.items()}
    assert all(mapping[ord(d)] == chr(c) for c, d in mapping.items())
    return str.maketrans(mapping)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a translation table from the a file specified on the command line,
    # or from the first 13 lines of stdin if no filename is given.
    translation = grid_to_translation(fileinput() if len(argv) > 1 else stdin)

    # Then use it to encrypt all subsequent input lines.
    for text in stdin:
        print(text.translate(translation), end='')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is neat and nicely done, there is not much to say. Just a few nitpicks:

- `fileinput()` already defaults to `stdin` if there is no arguments on the command line, no need to manage it yourself.
  It has been made clearer in a comment that you expect more than "no filename = stdin" : you should make it more clear in the code too; maybe changing the second line of comment with something like `# since fileinput will truncate anything to the 13 lines we need, overide the 'no filename = stdin' rule to be able to pipe in the grid + some text to translate`.
- You can easily use `'\'` in docstrings by using raw multiline strings: `r'''docstring'''`.
  Thus when defining `input` you can use `'\\'` as in a regular Python session, or use raw strings where applicable.

  Or use raw strings all along and add padding characters for those that ends with a backslash, as you already ignore them; and document it with something along the lines of `# avoid ending raw strings with backslashes, extra characters are ignored anyway`.
- You can extract the building of the various constants out of the function, there is no need to do it each time.
- You can define the magic number 13 as `MID_ALPHABET = len(ascii_lowercase) / 2`

Comment: Try it, though, and you may see the reasons for my workarounds. `fileinput` alone won't let me read the key from a file and the plaintext from stdin. Raw strings fail if the last character is a backslash.

Comment: When `fileinput` reads from `stdin`, either because there is no arguments or because there is a `'-'` on the command line, it doesn't process lines as you type it. You have to explicitly hit Ctrl+D to close the file before `fileinput` yields the lines. But you can still read from `stdin` later on. As long as you use `fileinput.input()` and thus accept that behaviour if the user enters `-` as first parameters, you might as well use it as the default. But I understand that your workaround lets you pipe the grid into the program and still access `stdin` later.

Comment: Included some of the comments in the answer.